# makepkg-mingw on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, mingw32

I'm trying to use Ubuntu to create a Windows app, following the steps outlined on [this page](https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/08/01/how-to-build-your-gtk-application-on-windows/). Is it possible to install makepkg-mingw on Ubuntu? Or is there a dedicated Ubuntu or Debian equivalent to this? I know about dpkg-deb, but that only creates a package for Debian and Ubuntu machines -- what I'm looking for is a utility that will create packages for Windows systems.